# Parse React page as a string

Tags: reactjs, oraclize

I have a [react page](https://datafeed-api.herokuapp.com), it simply shows some live data:

> {
>   "portfolioValue": 0.06, "usdEth": 94.82
>   }

I wanted to parse it using [oraclize](http://app.oraclize.it/home/test_query). But I can't because it's not a plain HTML page and React should render it first. So, how to parse the data?

Comment: You need to learn about react and how it works more.

Comment: You need to render the page with headless browser (or possibly JSDOM), or reverse-engineer it and parse sources where data originates from instead.

Comment: Your react page seems to be broken, can you fix it?